# Problema com sintaxe em e-mail

Tags: gramática, sintaxe

Recebi recentemente um e-mail e achei confusa a escrita. Gostaria de saber quais erros foram cometidos, e sobre a escrita abaixo, o que se entende.

> Hoje teremos nosso grande baile e para aqueles que não tomarem cerveja
>   e não gostarem de drinks, tipo caipirinha, foi acordado com o buffet
>   rolha livre!
>
> Será disponibilizado gelo, para acompanhar outras
>   bebidas. Portanto, quem quiser levar sua bebida, pode ficar à vontade!

Comment: A mensagem diz que você pode levar sua própria bebida (exceto cerveja e drinks, pelo que entendi). Isso seria o "rolha livre". Gelo não precisa levar, eles fornecem.

Comment: Então conforme está escrito, teria que levar refrigerante?

Comment: O texto não é 100% claro. Você *pode* levar seu refrigerante se quiser. Talvez o próprio local também venda refrigerantes, não sei.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quanto ao significado, concordo com [a leitura do @bfavaretto](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/1602/157#comment4442_1602):

> A mensagem diz que você *pode* levar sua própria bebida (exceto cerveja e drinks, pelo que entendi). Isso seria o "rolha livre". Gelo não precisa levar, eles fornecem.
> É possível, sem certeza, que o próprio local também venda refrigerantes.

---

Quanto a correções gramaticais, eu sugiro:

> Hoje teremos nosso grande baile, e para aqueles que não tomem cerveja ou não gostem de drinks, tipo caipirinha, foi acordado o buffet rolha livre!
>
> Será disponibilizado gelo, para acompanhar outras bebidas. Portanto, quem quiser levar sua bebida pode ficar à vontade!

- "tomem", "gostem";
- Remover "com" perto do fim do primeiro parágrafo;
- Remover a segunda vírgula do último parágrafo, para não separar o sujeito ("quem quiser levar sua bebida") do verbo.